# Why is my angular routeProvider not working?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have defined the controller as well as the `$routeProvider` but somehow the webpage does not redirect to `#/City` which is the default view. Both the template files exist inside partials folder. So I think no problem there.Can someone tell me why is this code not working??

```
  <html ng-app="MyApp">
    <head>
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Using Routes</h1>
        <div>
            <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
        <script>
            var app = angular.module("MyApp",['ngRoute']);

            app.config(function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider
                    .when('/City',
                    {
                        templateUrl:'partials/filterByCity.html',
                        controller:'MainController'

                    })
                    .when('/Name',
                    {
                        templateUrl:'partials/filterByName.html',
                        controller:'MainController'

                    })
                    .otherwise({
                        redirectTo:'/City'
                    });
            });

            app.controller("MainController",function($scope){
                $scope.customers=[
                    {name:"Mohd Kamran",city:"Bareilly"},
                    {name:"Nalin Gupta",city:"Lucknow"},
                    {name:"Akash Gupta",city:"Agra"}
                ];
            });

        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included `angular-route.min.js` in your `HTML`

Comment: That works, but the template is not loaded in the ng-view container